# Need to put dynamically generated (PHP) data into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database

I have a simple jQuery function, like this:

```
$(foo).bar({
   data:{
      //HERE GOES SOME PREFORMATTED DATA FROM DATABASE ACCESSIBLE BY PHP FUNCTION
   },
});
```

How do I do this? Thanks, cheers!

Comment: Please give us a clue as to WHAT data you are trying to add in there ___It makes a difference___ if you want a decent answer

Comment: Is this javascript code being generated inline in a PHP script?

Comment: Or are you asking how to write some AJAX code

Comment: @RiggsFolly looks like the OP doesn't like commenting a lot, he only accept answers

Comment: The data has to be a json object, keys are custom taxonomy terms from wordpress, values are null.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Response makes it obvious this is a _do it for me_ question and therefore _far too broad_

Comment: @RiggsFolly It was by no means a do it for me question, I just have no idea, how to do this. I've tried echoing the script (which is considered bad pratcice, and didn't even work). I have no further ideas.

Comment: Then do some reseach on AJAX

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, fortunately others were able to understand my question and answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, which is not completely coded. please, refer [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) for further queries.

```
$(foo).bar({
   data:{
   $.ajax({
     url: "complete_path.php", 
     success: function(result){
     console.log(result); // Process your data as per the requirement.
   }});
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is essentially the same solution, as above, which I accepted earlier.